# Precision parameter in plt.spy (matplotlib, sparse matrices)

Tags: matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to use `plt.spy(matrix)` and would to like to understand what the precision parameter does here. The [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.spy.html) states that any values of `|Z| > precision` will be plotted. But what does `|Z|` represent here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|Z|` means converting elements to their absolute values or taking modulus on each element.

This means `plt.spy(matrix, precision = k)` will plot elements from the matrix whose absolute value is greater than *k*.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

data = np.array([[1, -1, 0, -10], [0, 0, 20, 0], [90, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=4)

ax[0].spy(data, precision=-0.5)
ax[1].spy(data, precision=5)
ax[2].spy(data, precision=10)
ax[3].spy(data, precision=80)

plt.show()
```

This gives:
[image]

However, I feel this needs to be explicitly mentioned in the documentation as it is confusing what `|Z|` means.